# How to create ramdisc for Prestashop cache on Debian

Tags: memory, debian, cache, disc, tmpfs

Recently I was struggling to create ram disk for Prestashop cache folder which will have read and write privilages. I am using Apache + Nginx (as reverse proxy) and **PHP-FPM 5.6**  (soon moving to 7.2)

When I mounted this cache in in **etc/fstab** by using

```
tmpfs /var/www/virtual/domain.pl/htdocs/cache/smarty/cache tmpfs defaults,size=768M,mode=0755 0 0
```

and run **mount -a** entire shop went down with 500 erros. I can login as root to this Debian driven VPS.

When I type **mount -l** I can see my record added:

```
tmpfs on /var/www/virtual/domain.pl/htdocs/cache/smarty/cache type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=786432k,mode=0755)
```

I apache error log I found these errors:

```
 [proxy:error] [pid 29096:tid 140317986412288] (2)No such file or directory: AH02454: FCGI: attempt to connect to Unix domain socket /var/run/php5-fpm-domain.pl.sock (*) failed
[Mon Aug 10 14:52:37.667220 2020] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 29096:tid 140317986412288] [client 66.249.***.***:17018] AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: httpd-UDS
```

What is wrong with this command above or what should I do to make it work? I can see that it cannot write on the disk but what is the cause of this?

Yes, I realize that after restart cache will be removed from RAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that group and user didn't had permision to access because it was created by root, with root as a owner so I needed to add:

```
uid=<user_id_here>, gid=<group_id_here>
```

right after mode parameter.

To get id of desired group or user u needed to type:

```
id -u username
```

or

```
id -g groupname
```